# `python: not found` error when fetching Chromium source with `depot_tools`

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, chromium

I'm recently following the [Chromium build instructions for Windows](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/windows_build_instructions.md) but `fetch` yields the following error:

```
$ fetch chromium
/c/src/depot_tools/fetch: line 8: exec: python: not found
```

NB: Python 3.6 is already installed on my PC.

Comment: So you apparently don't have python 2 installed? What's the question?

Comment: Python 3.6 is already installed on my pc and I already add it to the path but depot_tools show this error

Comment: Python 2 is required.

Comment: If you're just doing DevTools development, see [Run Chrome with your own DevTools frontend](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1WNF-KqRSzPLUUfZqQG5AFeU_Ll8TfWYcJasa_XGf7ro/edit#heading=h.n5lej74lkll) for an easier setup workflow.

Comment: You should install depot_tools which will install the required version of Python which is 2.x right now. You should also add the path of that python exe from your depot_tools folder to env variable then it will work.

Comment: Thanks,  Kayce Basques  link is helpful..

Answer (score 1):

The Windows build instructions fail to specify the required Python version, but [the Linux ones](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/linux_build_instructions.md) are clear:

> **System requirements**
>
> - A 64-bit Intel machine with at least 8GB of RAM. More than 16GB is highly recommended.
> - At least 100GB of free disk space.
> - You must have Git and **Python v2** installed already.

The executable for Python 3.x is `python3`, and the one for Python 2.x is `python`, therefore you need to install Python 2.x.

Comment: The Linux ones also failed to specify the required Python version: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/main/docs/linux/build_instructions.md